# How to tell which object uses which animation/action

Tags: python, animation, scripting, export

I have a scene with multiple objects, each potentially using multiple actions.

I want to export the keyframes for each action with my own Python script, but only for the object that uses that action.

I see that each action has a user count, but I can't figure out how it keeps track of which objects use it. I know how to export the keyframes, but I can't find a way to associate actions with only certain objects.

Is this even possible? If not, how do other people deal with this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actions are globally stored in `bpy.data.actions`, regardless of scenes.

Every object can reference one and only one action ([Object.animation_data.action](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.types.AnimData.html#bpy.types.AnimData.action)). Thus, you can't know which actions are made for / compatible with which objects without extra work on the user oder coder side.

- User-based solution:
  Let the user specify which actions are supposed to be exported for which objects, either in a Panel in the export file selector or for every object in the object tab - both are not ideal. The former needs to be re-done every time (unless presets are used), in the latter renaming actions will break it.
- Programmatic solution:
  Check all FCurves' `data_path`s and see if these properties are available for your object type. This should work reliable to distinguish Armature actions from other more generic ones, as the data paths start with `'pose.bones'` for Pose actions.

Comment: I went with a combination of those two things.

Answer (score 4):

It's also actually possible to have multiple actions associated with a single object via the NLA editor and the tracks therein. In my exporter, I am using this and muting the NLA tracks for animations that are not currently active.

Here's the routine I use to gather all of the actions from the object and all of it's NLA tracks:

```py
def get_all_actions(obj):
  """Retrieve all actions given a blender object. Includes NLA-actions"""
  if obj.animation_data:
    if obj.animation_data.action:
      yield obj.animation_data.action
    for track in obj.animation_data.nla_tracks:
      for strip in track.strips:
        yield strip.action
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution might be to name the action using the name of the target object.

For example, if you want multiple actions for an object named *Cube*, then name your actions Cube_Action1, Cube_Action2, etc...
Or you might use Action1[Cube], Jump[Cube] etc...

Don't name it Cube.001 because that would clash with a copied object of that name.

In your export script, look through the actions, and then associate them with the object of the same name.